# Sequelize doesn`t close connection

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

i have a problem with a connection, it doesnt disconnect. I have an array with 3273 items and I was mapping the list and create all items individually, but at the end the connection doesnt close, please help !!!!

```js
function set_db(products_list) {
    products_list.map(function(p) {
        SupplierProduct.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                product_code: p.ProductCode
            },
            defaults: {
                oem_numbers: p.OemNumbers,
                description: p.Description,
                description2: p.Description2,
                weight: p.Weight,
                normal_dealer_cost: p.NormalDealerCost,
                suggested_sell_price: p.SuggestedSellPrice,
                product_classification_code: p.ProductClassificationCode,
                battery_type_or_page_yields: p.BatteryTypeOrPageYields,
                also_fits: p.AlsoFits,
                units: p.Units,
                prod_url: p.ProdUrl
            }
        }).spread((product, created) => {
            console.log(product);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }).finally(() => sequelize.close());
    });
}
```

After function ends the connection doesn´t close.